# How does $F_j \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial(F_j F_j)}{dx_i}$

Tags: summation, vectors

How does $$F_j \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial(F_j F_j)}{\partial x_i}$$

For $\mathbf{F}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ being a continuously differentiable vector field?

Comment: wouldn't your $dx_i$ be $\partial x _i$?

Comment: Yes, that was just a mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the use of Libeniz' rule:

$$\frac{\partial(F_j F_j)}{\partial x_i}=F_j\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i}F_j=2F_j\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i}.$$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\partial_{x_i}F_jF_j = (\partial_{x_i}F_j)F_j + F_j\partial_{x_i}F_j = 2 F_j\partial_{x_i}F_j
$$
this is true for $F_j$ having the same index. i.e. $F_j=x$ then
$$
x\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x_i}
$$
this is different when we are trying to compute the relationship for
$$
F_j\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_i}
$$
for example